# In how far does involvement in certain undertaking effects one, good or bad?

Tags: vipassana, abhidhamma, right-view

In how far does one take part on skilfull or unskilfull undertaking?

In how far does one receives the fruits of good or bad actions by means of getting involved by toughts, signs and deeds, by assosiation with tendencies and certain objectives and aims?

Are there even disadvantages, benefits, for one if just seeming for others to be near of certain undertakings?

And how should common-kamma here be understood?

*(Note that question in Dhamma is not dedicated for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but as a means to make merits toward release from this wheel)*

Comment: Ven Sir, I have noticed you have opened a new bounty but not voted on or accepted any of the answers given. Doing so is all up to you. But this will mean the bounty will get "wasted" when it expires.

Comment: My person leaves it up to the community, the system and to ones Nissaya. It's abounded with a blessing, Upasaka, and can not be of waste. My person thought longer about how to get ride of much reputations and it would be not proper to transfer them back into the world, give them householders personally. He also does not make use of voting generally since it is better to comment and know of who approves or disapproves. In this matter one should not think that ones good gifts are not regarded. So double+ merits if answering the "bounties" with same state of mind, toward Tripple Gems and Nibbana.

Comment: Good opportunity to possible engage in a transaction on one side or even two sides purified, Upasaka @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena and not at all one should fear that there could be a lose by giving into it, yet very insecure to receive direct reputations. Good training for one self, btw. [Vanna-maccharia, stinginess in regard of ones reputations: What to practice to get ride of it?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/33598/vanna-maccharia-stinginess-in-regard-of-ones-reputations-what-to-practice-to-g) (had a bounty of 500)

Comment: The site would also let users put a bounty on someone else's question (if you think it's a good or difficult question while you'd like more people to try to answer).

Comment: That would be a possibility, yes. How ever, those having given reputation before and also others, would easy say "look he likes to benefit..." or "or how could be give up reputation giving in faith for him, this or that...", how ever, sometimes it has been made already. And if seeing an answer good if answered, why not answering by oneself? So is really not easy to carry such around and has much "burden" of responsibility, if holding, received for the Juwels.

Comment: There are also less questions not answered yet. If doing such on questions which have already answers, but highly wrong answers much upvoted...? Just to give a sample. It's not for exchange made, not to forget, but for giving possibility to make releasing high merits.

Answer (score 0):

If:

- rejoice in others' action - mental approval
- partake in the activity

one accumulates common karma.

Also, being encouraged or not (sasañkhārikam / asañkhārikam) does matters. This reduces potency. In case of doing something as a group, not everyone will have the same motivation. If one is self-motivated karmic potential is high. If one loses motivation and seeds some self-encouragement it is lesser. If one needs external encouragement it will be even lesses.

If a group is taking some negative action. One should disassociate with the negative action and also not rejoice in that is being done. One should encourage others to disassociate. One should not encourage anyone to do what is negative.

If a group is taking some positive action. One should associate with the positive action and also rejoice in that is being done. One should encourage others to associate. If one's motivation lapses one should encourage oneself.

If one is a monk being suspected of doing wrong may discredit the institution/order of monks. So it best to be mindful of if this happens. For a layperson disassociating mentally is enough to prevent karmic repercussions, as karma is volition based, but wise even not to appear as associated as this will have social consequences.

Even if one does not have the means to participate or do a positive action if one mentally approved it then one partakes the merit. If one is indifferent or does not approve one does not get karmic results. Same is true for negative actions.

Comment: Sadhu Upasaka. One thing that comes to mind is that the Buddha warned "even if not mental involved, approve by thoughts, one becomes suspected by good fellows, and may have disadvantages, losing them". What about such? Is mind here enough? Or does disapprove requires clear signs and actions for security? "partake in the activity"= body, speech, signs, right?

Comment: "rejoice in others' action", approve, agrees, ignores in ways "that is not my problem" and takes benefits from it anyhow (cheating one self, a-sacca), right?

Answer (score 0):

The Noble Eightfold Path ends kamma (AN 6.63). Therefore, those minds free from self-view can engage in any necessary quantity of skillful undertaking without reaping negative results, such as paranoid neurosis that occurs to those unskillfully craving the Path who generally view anatta as annihilationism or vibhava.